# Подмена домена на поддомен url на htacess

Tags: .htaccess, поддомены

очень был бы признателен если б кто помог в таком вопросе
есть url
[http://сайт.ру/search/country,Italy](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/search/country,Italy)
мне необходимо изменить его на такой с поддоменом
[http://italy.сайт.ру/search/country,Italy](http://italy.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/search/country,Italy)
то биш содержимое [http://сайт.ру/search/country,Italy](http://%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/search/country,Italy)
показать в [http://italy.сайт.ру/search/country,Italy](http://italy.%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82.%D1%80%D1%83/search/country,Italy)
При этом к параметрам регионов еще добавляется параметр категории.
тоесть нужно заменять только часть с доменом.

Comment: Не совсем по теме. В web-стандартах специально зарезервирован домен example.com, чтобы указывать его в примерах url вместо всяких выдуманных сайт.ру

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, в чем именно состоит вопрос: вы не знаете как настроить ваш web-сервер на подмены или не можете придумать само правило подмены?

Comment: 1-Извиняюсь за сайт.ру (первый раз пишу на подобном сервисе обычно находил ответы сам ,в   гугле

Comment: 2. Сервер вроде настроил но в osclas все равно не работают поддомены.Хочу сделать переадресацию с помощью htacess

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, то что вы уже пробовали. И приведите пример с другими параметрами в url